# Return a date based on criteria in excel

Tags: excel, date, match

I have a table of `athlete names`, `training sessions` and `completion dates`.

From this table, I want to extract the most recent dates (excluding the current date) that a specific athlete completed a specific session.

So far my formula is as follows:

```
= IF (MATCH ($AC27&$AD27
            ,'Data'!$A$2:$A$2000 & 'Data'!$BS$2:$BS$2000
            , 0
            )
     ,MAX(('Data'!$B$2:$B$2000 < $AE$1) * 'Data'!$B$2:$B$2000)
     ,
     )
```

where

```
'Data'!        - Threshold Efforts Data Entry sheet
$AC$27         - specific athlete name 
AD$27          - specific athlete session 
$A$2:$A$2000   - lookup array for athlete names
$BS$2:$BS$2000 - look up array for sessions
$B$2:$B$2000   - look up array for dates
$AE$1          - the current date
```

The formula works, however it returns the most recent date, rather than the most recent date matched for the athlete name and session.

Where have I gone wrong ?

Comment: If you have `MAXIFS` you can look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
=MAX(IF($A$5:$A$12=D5,IF($B$5:$B$12<$B$1,$B$5:$B$12)))
```

It's an array function, so click in the cell and press ctrl + shift + enter.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works for me when using athlete name. I;m still having trouble working in the session name but I think that is due to an issue with the way the session name is coded.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow your cell references. You can use a combination of `SUMPRODUCT` and `MAX`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((A1:A13=AC27)*(BS1:BS13=AD27)*B1:B13))
```

Here's the result:

[image]